# MustacheJS Conditionally Show DOM

Tags: jquery, mustache

I am using [navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) and [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) to build a single-page application, but running into an issue conditionally showing DOM.

This is my mustache template:

```html
<script id="interface-upsert" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <a href="#/" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm my-3" role="button">&larr; Go Back</a>
    <form class="border rounded p-4 mb-3">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>{{ title }}</legend>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" value="{{ firstName }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" value="{{ lastName }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="{{ email }}" />
                </div>
                {{#id}}
                <div class="col-12 form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-1">Update</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Reset</button>
                    {{#isActive}}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Deactivate</button>
                    {{/isActive}}
                    {{^isActive}}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Reactivate</button>
                    {{/isActive}}
                </div>
                {{/id}}
                {{^id}}
                <div class="col-12 form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-1">Create</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Reset</button>
                </div>
                {{/id}}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</script>
```

And this is my navigo router setup:

```js
var router = new Navigo(null, true, '#');
router
    .on('/create', function () {
        var viewModel = {
            id: null,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            isActive: true
        };
        var template = document.getElementById('interface-upsert').innerHTML;
        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, { title: 'Create User' });
        $('#interface-layout').html(rendered);
    })
.resolve();
```

I would expect for when the `id` property in my view model is false that the update, reset, and either deactivate or reactivate buttons to be visible. Inversely when the `id` property is set to true, that the create and reset buttons would be displayed.

However, what's going on right now is that it is always displaying it as if `id` is set to a truthy value (like 1). Am I missing something?

Comment: You are not using your `viewModel` anywhere, what's the point of that then?

Comment: @Tomalak the viewModel is being used throughout the template. Later on I plan on using the form values in an AJAX call. This example has just the `create` route setup, but the `edit` route that I indent on setting up (that uses the same template) will specify the property values and hopefully show/hide the buttons that I'm trying to conditionally setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my issue. I was passing an object `{ title: 'Create User' }` instead of the viewmodel. To fix the issue, I changed my viewmodel to include the title and passed the viewmodel when rendering the template like such:

```js
var viewModel = {
    title: 'Create User',
    id: null,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    isActive: true
};
var template = document.getElementById('interface-upsert').innerHTML;
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, viewModel);
$('#interface-layout').html(rendered);
```